# insert something into kill ring in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, yank, kill-ring

I want to write a function that will insert the file name of the current buffer into the kill ring so I can yank it to the terminal in another window. How can I programmatically insert a string into the kill ring?

```
(<SOME FUNCTION> (buffer-file-name))
```

Is there a (built-in) function for that or do I need to insert the string I want into a buffer and then kill it?

I tried something like this:

```lisp
(defun path ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((begin (mark)))
      (insert (buffer-file-name))
      (kill-region begin (mark)))))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a function for that:

```lisp
(defun copy-buffer-name ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (buffer-file-name)))
```

Comment: You may prefere ``buffer-name`` instead of ``buffer-file-name``. Because some buffers are not related to a file.

Comment: @yvesBaumes `buffer-file-name` is fine because I need it only to grab filename.

Comment: @jcubic Then be aware that `(buffer-file-name)` can be `nil`, which would make `kill-new` signal an error.  You should guard the expression with `(when (buffer-file-name) …)`

Comment: @lunaryorn Ok, my function is now: `(let ((path (buffer-file-name)))
    (when path
      (kill-new path)))`